# how to update the password for login in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to update the password for login

what I am doing in my application when user login then after seeing their own profile

student.cs

```
namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class student
    {
        public int studentid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string firstname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "LastName")]
        public string lastname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Emailid")]
        public string emailid { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["username"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(getcurrentstudent());
            }
        }

        public student getcurrentstudent()       
        {
            var currentusername = Session["username"].ToString();
            var currentpassword = Session["password"].ToString();
            var currentstu = _dbcontextstud.stud.Where(s => s.username == currentusername && s.password == currentpassword).SingleOrDefault();

            return currentstu;
        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(student stud)
        {
            var login = _dbcontextstud.stud.Where(x => x.username == stud.username && x.password == stud.password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (login != null)
            {
                Session["username"] = login.username.ToString();
                Session["password"] = login.password.ToString();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        public ActionResult create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult create(student stud)
        {
            var create = _dbcontextstud.stud.Add(stud);
            _dbcontextstud.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model Demo.Models.student

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (Session["username"] != null)
{
    <text>Welcome <strong>@Session["username"].ToString()</strong></text>
}

<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout")

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.emailid)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**database diagram:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwSr.png]

**see reference when I log in:**

[image]

how to update the password for login in MVC or which field extra need to add a table for update the password or which logic implement for update the password?

**please help**

Comment: You create a POST endpoint that accepts the username along with the current and new password, validates the password according to the requirements, then hashes it and updates the database record when all is well. What you're asking here, is for us to write this for you, and that isn't going to happen. Also, don't roll your own authentication system, just use ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you simply need to update a database property using Entity Framework.

1. Get the item from database: `_dbcontextstud.stud.FirstOrDefault()`
2. Change the item property: `user.Password = model.NewPassword`
3. Save the changes: `_dbcontextstud.SaveChanges()`

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    var currentUsername = Session["username"].ToString();
    var currentPassword = model.CurrentPassword;
    
    var user = _dbcontextstud.stud.FirstOrDefault(s => s.username == currentUsername && s.password == currentPassword);
    if(user == null)
    {
        // user password did not match the DB password
        throw new Exception("Invalid password exception");
    }

    // update the new password
    user.Password = model.NewPassword;
    
    // save the Database changes
    _dbcontextstud.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// view model
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```